# adb shell cmd package compile not working

Tags: android, adb

### Overview

I execute the command: `adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f my-package`

immediately returned Success.

Next, I determine success with the following command.
`adb shell dumpsys package my-package`

The relevant result is as follows.

```
Dexopt state:
  [my-package]
    path: /data/app/~~RlA_7phUWI_QeKL5Ez0VaQ==/my-package-8Q64dwzm_qioAdSVBF3J5g==/base.apk
      arm64: [status=speed-profile] [reason=bg-dexopt]
      odex file size: base.art: 4712Kb base.odex: 6408Kb base.vdex: 82542Kb
```

The above information shows that `[status=speed-profile] [reason=bg-dexopt]` did not work.

### My cell phone information

Basic Information:

- adb Version: 33.0.2-8557947
- Android version: 12
- Kernel version: 5.10.66
- Whether to root: No

System Properties:

```bash
# Note: Only useful information is listed

$ adb shell getprop

[dalvik.vm.usejit]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.usejitprofiles]: [true]

[pm.dexopt.ab-ota]: [speed-profile]
[pm.dexopt.bg-dexopt]: [speed-profile]
[pm.dexopt.boot-after-ota]: [verify]
[pm.dexopt.cmdline]: [verify]
[pm.dexopt.first-boot]: [verify]
[pm.dexopt.first-use]: [speed-profile]
[pm.dexopt.inactive]: [verify]
[pm.dexopt.install]: [speed-profile]
[pm.dexopt.install-bulk]: [speed-profile]
[pm.dexopt.install-bulk-downgraded]: [verify]
[pm.dexopt.install-bulk-secondary]: [verify]
[pm.dexopt.install-bulk-secondary-downgraded]: [extract]
[pm.dexopt.install-fast]: [skip]
[pm.dexopt.post-boot]: [extract]
[pm.dexopt.shared]: [speed]
```

### My Discovery Process

The following logs were obtained via logcat.

```
PackageManager: Skipped dexOpt for start by shell: my-package
```

Looking at the Android code, the compilation process returns PackageDexOptimizer.DEX_OPT_SKIPPED

In the DexOptHelper class, there is the following code.

```java
    /*package*/ boolean performDexOpt(DexoptOptions options) {
        final Computer snapshot = mPm.snapshotComputer();
        if (snapshot.getInstantAppPackageName(Binder.getCallingUid()) != null) {
            return false;
        } else if (snapshot.isInstantApp(options.getPackageName(), UserHandle.getCallingUserId())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (options.isDexoptOnlySecondaryDex()) {
            return mPm.getDexManager().dexoptSecondaryDex(options);
        } else {
            int dexoptStatus = performDexOptWithStatus(options);
            return dexoptStatus != PackageDexOptimizer.DEX_OPT_FAILED;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the non-SecondaryDex case is considered successful as long as the result is not PackageDexOptimizer.DEX_OPT_FAILED.

### My Questions

**Question 1: Why did the `adb shell cmd package compile` command return Success but did not take effect?**

My answer. Referring to the log message above, it was ignored and processed by the system

**Question 2: I compile a random package that does not exist, but it also returns Success. e.g. `adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f not-found-package`**

Same answer as question 1

**Question 3: Why is dexOpt not allowed to run in the shell?**

### Additional Information

#### Related codes

- https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerShellCommand.java#L1771

#### Logs

Adjust the logging level to verbose inside the developer mode.

The following logs are obtained via logcat.

```
PackageManager: Skipped dexOpt for start by shell: my-package
```

Comment: I am not sure if I have fully understand how dexopt works, but from what I have read it seems to me that `cmd package compile` only sets the optimization properties and bg-dexopt then performs the actual optimization. That would explain your result, setting the properties was directly a success but without running bg-dexopt no optimization will be executed.

Comment: @Robert I have tried to execute `adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f my-package` and then execute `adb shell cmd package bg-dexopt-job`, again no change. By looking at the log of bg-dexopt, we know that the original targetFilter(speed-profile) is still used.